# My object became very dense with faces and made it become black when previewing it. How do I fix this?

Tags: rendering, 3d-view

The materials were working fine but I don't remember when or how it happened but the donut became black at every view.
[image]

[image]

I realize it became very dense with faces and the black is actually all the vertices. I can see the color fine when zoomed in.

[image]

I do not have any subsurface modifiers on the object nor do I think I modified anything when this issue happened. How would I go about fixing this?

Expected Outcome: The donut/icing has less faces while previewing it so I can work with it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have never done donut tutorial before so I don't know what steps did you follow but you somehow had to use subdivision with very hight number and somehow even apply it... There are basically 3 options you have

1. Try to use **Multiresolution Modifier** on your dense object and click **Unsubdivide** It's purpose is to rebuild a lower subdivision level of the current base mesh. It may not work, but it can... If it does then click unsubdivide until it is no more dense
2. Try to use **Remesh** modifier, it will destroy your topology, but it can save it.
3. If nothing works, do it again from scratch

Good luck

Comment: If someone knows more option, teach me I will be happy to learn new possibilities

Comment: You could also use the "decimate" modifier

Comment: There are also tools like [Instant Meshes](https://github.com/wjakob/instant-meshes)

Comment: Well that's embarrassing, it was because wireframe is on. I get confused between x-ray mode, wireframe, edit mode. Looks like this novice still have far more learning to go.